# Creating Bootstrap grid dynamically

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use a JavaScript function to generate bootstrap columns dynamically. The goal is to have them displayed in a single row as different columns.[image]

Currently this is how it looks like:

I am calling this function on window.onload() with the div id:

```
// Update the bootstrap grid once the tasks are added
function updateTaskContainerHead(containerId){
    let containerHead = document.getElementById(containerId);
    // Take the row headings and make an HTML container out of them
    let tblRowHeadings = ['Task Name','Assigned To','Priority','Due Date',''];
    let tblHeadRow = document.createElement("div");
    tblHeadRow.classname="row";
    for (let heading of tblRowHeadings){
        let tblHeadCell = document.createElement("div");
        tblHeadCell.className="col";
        let cellText = document.createTextNode(heading);
        tblHeadCell.appendChild(cellText);
        tblHeadRow.appendChild(tblHeadCell);
    }
    containerHead.appendChild(tblHeadRow);
}
```

and the HTML component is just:

```
<lead>Completed Tasks</lead>
<div class="container" id="ongoingTasksContainer">
```

What do you think might be the problem?

Comment: Hi Swopnil, if you found that my answer answered your question please upvote and/or accept it. If you still have outstanding questions please let me know and I'd be glad to help out where I can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a spello .. well case sensitive one:

```
tblHeadRow.classname="row";
```

should be:

```
tblHeadRow.className="row";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `tblHeadRow` class correctly.

You need to use `element.classList.add(className)` method. [(docs)](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp)

If you use this instead you will have columns:

```
tblHeadRow.classList.add("row");
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsme6rhy/) for reference.

---

However, I would really recommend using a table in this situation. If you're creating a `tbl`, `head` and `cell` it seems like a table is what you're after and [bootstrap has helper classes for those](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) as well.